# php format field datetime-local in to php

Tags: php, html, datetimepicker

i have this input which i take like this

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

which i am inserting in the db successfully. In the database it stores as such in my table

```
2021-05-17 23:00:00
```

but then i am trying to display it in my page like so

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $date_time; ?>" >
```

but it gives me a blank field

but when i inspect it shows my the correct value in the value field

Comment: 2 issue there :- `<` missing and `"` missing in `input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $date_time; ?> >`

Comment: @AlivetoDie not the issue bro just forgot to type it in here

Comment: Also you need to provide date in this format:- `<input type="datetime-local" value="2019-12-10T03:10" >`

Comment: @AlivetoDie i do not follow

Comment: what do you mean by "i do not follow"

Comment: Try and highlight the contents of the "empty" field. Is it possible the text is there and just transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**get datetime from database using DATE_FORMAT()**

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') AS custom_date
```

**and after fetching data in which variable your data exist use that in your input value**

```
<input type='datetime-local' name='datetime' value='<?php echo $row['custom_date'] ?>' >
```